# Read Shapefile on Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, shapefile

I am using an Azure Function written in python to read a shapefile that comes from a Blob. The configuration is

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "inputShp",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "uploads/shapefile/{name}.shp",
      "connection": "StorageConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the `__init__.py` script

```py
import logging
from json import dumps
import shapefile
import azure.functions as func

def main(inputShp: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                  f"Name: {inputShp.name}\n"
                  f"Blob Size: {inputShp.length} bytes")

    reader = shapefile.Reader(inputShp.read())
```

But this throws an error

```
Exception: ShapefileException: Shapefile Reader requires a shapefile or file-like object.
```

I have tried using `reader = shapefile.Reader(io.BytesIO(inputShp.read()))` instead, which gives the error

```
error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also load shapefiles from any Python file-like object using keyword arguments to specify any of the three files. This feature is very powerful and allows you to load shapefiles from a url, from a zip file, serialized object, or in some cases a database.

Below is the sample for the same

```
>>> myshp = open("shapefiles/blockgroups.shp", "rb")
>>> mydbf = open("shapefiles/blockgroups.dbf", "rb")
>>> r = shapefile.Reader(shp=myshp, dbf=mydbf)
```

Use open instead of read.Alternatively try the below sample

```
from __future__ import print_function
import zipfile
import StringIO
import shapefile

zipshape = zipfile.ZipFile(open(r'C:\GIS\Temp\RoadsShapefileFolder.zip', 'rb'))
print(zipshape.namelist())
dbfname, _, shpname, _, shxname = zipshape.namelist()
r = shapefile.Reader(shp=StringIO.StringIO(zipshape.read(shpname)),
                     shx=StringIO.StringIO(zipshape.read(shxname)),
                     dbf=StringIO.StringIO(zipshape.read(dbfname)))

print(r.bbox)
print(r.numRecords)
```

This should work too. Hope it helps.

Comment: The files are passed in as `func.InputStream`, so they are not on any "physical" location. Your solution only works if you open a file from a local location

Comment: Understood, It's not a right solution but can you download the blob and pass the path for the same for further request.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of using the `blob` from Azure and Azure Functions all together, which is not what the question is about. Currently I am doing this on a server, but I want to migrate to Azure Functions to make it better

Answer (score 0):

Reading shapefiles from a stream seems to be what the MemoryFile (or perhaps MemoryZipFile) of Fiona lets you do.

Not tested, but worth checking out.

https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fiona.html#fiona.io.MemoryFile

Comment: hum I will do some tests on `fiona` then

Comment: doesn't work, apparently there is no way to load more than one file with the `MemoryFile`, and for a shapefile we need to read the `shp`, `dbf` and `shx` files: https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/613

Comment: Ah. What you could do is to create a zip-file with the shapefile and all the sidecar-files) before putting it in the blob at the first place? And then use the MemoryZipFile

Comment: But I guess that shapefiles aren't the best format for doing stuff like this. Do you have the option to use another format, like geopackage?